# Using basic javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an input field whereby the user has to enter a phone number and it has to be exactly 10 numbers. My script isn't working and I'm wondering how to specify the 'exactly 10' part. At the moment it's just less than 10.

```js
 var contact_number = document.getElementById('number');
    input = contact_number.value
    if (input.length = 10){
        alert("The field needs to contain 10 numbers!")
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
    
    if (contact_number == ""){
        alert("You need to enter a Phone Number")
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<hr>

<!-- Clients details -->
 
    <p>Contact Person: <input id="contact" name="contact" type="text" placeholder="Type Full Name here"></p>
        
 
 <p>Contact Number: <input id="number" name="number" type="number" maxlength="10" placeholder="Type Number here"></p>
 
    
    <p>Email address: <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Email here"></p>
    
<hr>
```

Comment: Use `input.length === 10`. You have `input.length = 10` which is an assignment not a comparison.

Comment: is this question solved or not? you've been given answers and should be marked as solved by accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not equal operator `!=`

```js
 var contact_number = document.getElementById('number');
    input = contact_number.value
    if (input.length != 10){
        alert("The field needs to contain 10 numbers!")
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
    
    if (contact_number == ""){
        alert("You need to enter a Phone Number")
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<hr>

<!-- Clients details -->
 
    <p>Contact Person: <input id="contact" name="contact" type="text" placeholder="Type Full Name here"></p>
        
 
 <p>Contact Number: <input id="number" name="number" type="number" maxlength="10" placeholder="Type Number here"></p>
 
    
    <p>Email address: <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Email here"></p>
    
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first if-statement is off. I think you want it to say *not equals*. What you have currently is not a comparison, and will always go into the body of the if statement.

```
if (input.length != 10){
    alert("The field needs to contain 10 numbers!")
    return false
}
```